# Panel set to hidden and then visible loses textbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hope I can explain this properly.

I have a grid that is part of our 3rd party shopping cart software.  This grid has a row of quantity text boxes into which the customer enters how many of each thing they want to buy.

I put this grid inside a panel so I can set it on or off with

```
myPanel.Visible=true;
```

I also have a button to show and one to hide using the above code method.

If I enter a value into a textbox and then click the hide button and then click the show button, when the panel reappears the values are zero.  If I then reload the page (browser reload) then the value returns as it was originally.  It's a pretty good magic trick but not what I need.  What am I doing wrong?

Eventually I want to select a date from a calendar while it is hidden but that is not in play yet... just the show/hide buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the correct behaviour of `ASP.NET WebForms` and `ViewState`

1. **First page load**: Panel is visible and the panel loaded with its initial values.
2. **Hide Panel**: As soon as the button is pressed a post back occurs.  `myPanel` is set to invisible which on the server side means that the HTML for the panel is not generated (this can be confirmed by looking the generated HTML).
3. **Show Panel**: A post back occurs again.  But because the values were not rendered in the previous step, they are not available in the `ViewState` to repopulate the panel.
4. **Reload of the page**: This start the process over again (Same as step 1)

A possible solution is to instead hide the panel (`<div`) on the client-side.  This will also have the benefit of not making a round trip to the server to just enable/disable the panel.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Philip.  It was very helpful.  You got me thinking differently.  I ended up adding 2 classes to my CSS called Hide and Show that did a display:none and then set pnlMyPanel.CssClass to the proper one from the server side.  Again, thanks!

Comment: @Deverill, pleasure glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like below...

Show and Hide button definition to show/Hide the panel is in Java script. That mans there is no handler of Button click event at server side...This approach is suggested normally and fast..

---

**Sample ASPX Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Hide() {
        var ID = document.getElementById('pnl');
        ID.style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }

    function Show() {
        var ID = document.getElementById('btnHide');
        ID.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
</script>
<asp:panel id="pnl" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ed" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:panel>
<asp:button text="Hide" runat="server" id="Button1" onclientclick="return Hide();" />
<asp:button text="Show" runat="server" id="btnShow" onclientclick="return Show();" />
```

---

**Sample Code Behind**

```
public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (DataTable Dt = new DataTable())
            {
                using (DataColumn Dc = new DataColumn("Name"))
                {
                    Dt.Columns.Add(Dc);

                    DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
                    dr["name"] = "1";
                    Dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                    dr = Dt.NewRow();
                    dr["name"] = "2";
                    Dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                    grd.DataSource = Dt;
                    grd.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time creating the sample.

Comment: At the time, not really since I was exploring another method.  As it turns out I have a new need for exactly what you have provided.  Thanks.  +1